# Why can't F#'s type inference handle this?

Tags: f#, type-inference

I have a sequence of FileInfo, but I only care about their string names, so I want a sequence of string. At first I tried something like this:

```
Seq.map (fun fi -> fi.Name) fis
```

But for some reason, F#'s type inference isn't good enough to allow this, and made me explicitly give a type to "fi":

```
Seq.map (fun (fi : FileInfo) -> fi.Name) fis
```

Why is this annotation required? If it is known that `fis : seq<FileInfo>` and that `Seq.map : ('a -> 'b) -> seq<'a> -> seq<'b>`, then shouldn't it infer that the type of the lambda expression is `FileInfo -> 'b`, and then, from `fi.Name : string`, further infer that its type is `FileInfo -> string`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Type inference works left-to-right.  This is where the pipeline operator is useful; if you already know the type of 'fis', then write it as

```
fis |> Seq.map (fun fi -> fi.Name)
```

and the inference works for you.

(In general, expressions of the form

```
o.Property
o.Method args
```

require the type of 'o' to be known *a priori*; for most other expressions, when a type is not pinned down the inference system can 'float a constraint' along that can be solved later, but for these cases, there are no constraints of the form 'all types with a property named P' or 'all types with a method named M' (like duck typing) that can be postponed and solved later.  So you need that info now, or inference fails immediately.)

See also an [overview of type inference in F#](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1526.entry).

Comment: I hope they make the type inference more robust. I've already hit a few cases where I had to reorder the methods in a class or I would get too generic type errors.

Comment: For what its worth, this blog post and some of its comments have a useful explanation of some of F#'s strengths and weaknesses in its type checker: http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/12/f-from-haskell-perspective.html