# Haskell composition (.) vs F#'s pipe forward operator (|>)

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, composition

In F#, use of the the pipe-forward operator, `|>`, is pretty common.  However, in Haskell I've only ever seen function composition, `(.)`, being used.  I understand that they are [related](https://web.archive.org/web/20100330211824/http://blogs.msdn.com/chrsmith/archive/2008/06/14/function-composition.aspx), but is there a language reason that pipe-forward isn't used in Haskell or is it something else?

Comment: [lihanseys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144871/3021309) states that `&` is Haskell's `|>`. Buried deep in this thread and took me a few days to discover. I use it a lot, because you naturally read left to right to follow your code.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I am being a little speculative...

**Culture**: I think `|>` is an important operator in the F# "culture", and perhaps similarly with `.` for Haskell.  F# has a function composition operator `<<` but I think the F# community tends to use [points-free style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) less than the Haskell community.

**Language differences**: I don't know enough about both languages to compare, but perhaps the rules for generalizing let-bindings are sufficiently different as to affect this.  For example, I know in F# sometimes writing

```
let f = exp
```

will not compile, and you need explicit eta-conversion:

```
let f x = (exp) x   // or x |> exp
```

to make it compile.  This also steers people away from points-free/compositional style, and towards the pipelining style.  Also, F# type inference sometimes demands pipelining, so that a known type appears on the left (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844733/why-cant-fs-type-inference-handle-this)).

(Personally, I find points-free style unreadable, but I suppose every new/different thing seems unreadable until you become accustomed to it.)

I think both are potentially viable in either language, and history/culture/accident may define why each community settled at a different "attractor".

Comment: I agree with the cultural differences.  Traditional Haskell makes use of `.` and `$`, so people continue to use them.

Comment: Point free is sometimes more readable than pointful, sometimes less.  I generally use it in the argument to functions like map and filter, to avoid having a lambda cluttering things up.  I sometimes use it in top-level functions too, but less often and only when its something straightforward.

Comment: I don't see much culture in it, in the sense that there simply isn't much of a choice in the matter as far as F# is concerned (for the reasons you and Ganesh mention). So I'd say that both are viable in Haskell, but F# is definitely much better equipped for using the pipeline operator.

Comment: yes, the culture of reading left to right :) even math should be taught that way...

Comment: @nicolas left to right is an arbitrary choice. You can get used to right to left.

Comment: @MartinCapodici indeed. some people go top to bottom then right to left. it's all relative and arbitrary, and we can adapt to everything, but that's a pain

Comment: F# also has a composition operator `>>` that is essentially composition in left-to-right reading order. I.e., `let h = f >> g` means `let h x = x |> f |> g`. This allows you to write function composition that looks like the `|>` pipeline, but in point-free style: `let chain = add2 >> mult3 >> add1` is equivalent to `let chain x = x |> add2 |> mult3 |> add1`, *and* reads in the same order.

Answer (score 92):

In F# `(|>)` is important because of the left-to-right typechecking. For example:

```
List.map (fun x -> x.Value) xs
```

generally won't typecheck, because even if the type of `xs` is known, the type of the argument `x` to the lambda isn't known at the time the typechecker sees it, so it doesn't know how to resolve `x.Value`.

In contrast

```
xs |> List.map (fun x -> x.Value)
```

will work fine, because the type of `xs` will lead to the type of `x` being known.

The left-to-right typechecking is required because of the name resolution involved in constructs like `x.Value`. Simon Peyton Jones has written a [proposal](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/TypeDirectedNameResolution) for adding a similar kind of name resolution to Haskell, but he suggests using local constraints to track whether a type supports a particular operation or not, instead. So in the first sample the requirement that `x` needs a `Value` property would be carried forward until `xs` was seen and this requirement could be resolved. This does complicate the type system, though.

Comment: Interesting this is that there is (<|) operator similar to (.) in Haskell with the same direction of data right-to-left. But how will work type resolution for it?

Comment: (<|) is actually similar to Haskell's ($).

Left-to-right typechecking is only required for resolving things like .Value, so (<|) works fine in other scenarios, or if you use explicit type annotations.

Answer (score 47):

More speculation, this time from the predominantly Haskell side...

`($)` is the flip of `(|>)`, and its use is quite common when you can't write point-free code. So the main reason that `(|>)` not used in Haskell is that its place is already taken by `($)`.

Also, speaking from a bit of F# experience, I think `(|>)` is so popular in F# code because it resembles the `Subject.Verb(Object)` structure of OO. Since F# is aiming for a smooth functional/OO integration, `Subject |> Verb Object` is a pretty smooth transition for new functional programmers.

Personally, I like thinking left-to-right too, so I use `(|>)` in Haskell, but I don't think many other people do.

Comment: Hi Nathan, is "flip ($)" predefined anywhere in the Haskell platform? The name "(|>)" is already defined in Data.Sequence with another meaning. If not already defined, what do you call it? I'm thinking of going with "($>) = flip ($)"

Comment: @mattbh: Not that I can find with Hoogle. I didn't know about `Data.Sequence.|>`, but `$>` looks reasonable to avoid conflicts there. Honestly, there are only so many good-looking operators, so I would just use `|>` for both and manage conflicts on a case-by-case basis. (Also I would be tempted to just alias `Data.Sequence.|>` as `snoc`)

Comment: ($) just redefines the parsing associativity. It's not the same as forward composition -- you have to have names bound in scope. Try it yourself: http://pastebin.com/uEc2k612

Comment: `($)` and `(|>)` are application not composition. The two are related (as the question notes) but they are not the same (your `fc` is `(Control.Arrow.>>>)` for functions).

Comment: In practice, F#'s `|>` actually reminds me of the UNIX `|` more than anything else.

Comment: Another benefit of `|>` in F# is that it has nice properties for IntelliSense in Visual Studio. Type `|>`, and you get a list of functions that can be applied to the value on the left, similar to what happens when typing `.` after an object.

Answer (score 34):

I think we're confusing things. Haskell's (`.`) is equivalent to F#'s (`>>`). Not to be confused with F#'s (`|>`) which is just inverted function application and is like Haskell's (`$`) - reversed:

```
let (>>) f g x = g (f x)
let (|>) x f = f x
```

I believe Haskell programmers do use `$` often. Perhaps not as often as F# programmers tend to use `|>`. On the other hand, some F# guys use `>>` to a ridiculous degree: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashleyf/archive/2011/04/21/programming-is-pointless.aspx

Comment: as you say it's like Haskell's `$` operator - reversed, you can also easily defined it as: `a |> b = flip ($)` which becomes equivalent to F#'s pipeline e.g. you can then do `[1..10] |> map f`

Comment: I think  (`.`) the same as (`<<`), whereas (`>>`) is the reverse composition.  That is `( >> ) : ('T1 -> 'T2) -> ('T2 -> 'T3) -> 'T1 -> 'T3` vs `( << ) : ('T2 -> 'T3) -> ('T1 -> 'T2) -> 'T1 -> 'T3`

Comment: -1 for "use >> to a ridiculous degree".  (Well, I didn't but you got my point).  F in F# is for "functional", so function composition is legitimate.

Comment: Certainly I agree that function composition is legit. By "some F# guys" I'm referring to myself! That my own blog. :P

Comment: I don't think `.` is equivalent to `>>`. I don't know if F# has `<<` but that would be the equivalent (like in Elm).

Answer (score 32):

If you want to use F#'s `|>` in Haskell then in [Data.Function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html) is the `&` operator (since `base 4.8.0.0`).

Comment: Any reason for Haskell to choose `&` over `|>`? I feel like `|>` is much more intuitive, and it also reminds me of Unix pipe operator.

Comment: @yeshengm I find `&` very intuitive. Code nearly reads correctly in English by just pronouncing `&` as "and". For example: `5 & factorial & show` reads aloud as "take 5 and then take factorial of it and then apply show to it".

Answer (score 17):

I have seen `>>>` being used for `flip (.)`, and I often use that myself, especially for long chains that are best understood left-to-right.

`>>>` is actually from Control.Arrow, and works on more than just functions.

Comment: `>>>` is defined in `Control.Category`.

Answer (score 17):

#### Left-to-right composition in Haskell

Some people use left-to-right (message-passing) style in Haskell too. See, for example, [mps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mps) library on Hackage. An example:

```
euler_1 = ( [3,6..999] ++ [5,10..999] ).unique.sum
```

I think this style looks nice in some situations, but it's harder to read (one needs to know the library and all its operators, the redefined `(.)` is disturbing too).

There are also left-to-right as well as right-to-left composition operators in [Control.Category](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Category.html), part of the base package. Compare `>>>` and `<<<` respectively:

```
ghci> :m + Control.Category
ghci> let f = (+2) ; g = (*3) in map ($1) [f >>> g, f <<< g]
[9,5]
```

There is a good reason to prefer left-to-right composition sometimes: evaluation order follows reading order.

Comment: Nice, so (>>>) is largely equatable to (|>)?

Comment: @Khanzor Not exactly. (|>) applies an argument, (>>>) is mostly function composition (or similar things). Then I suppose there is some fixity difference (didn't check it).

Answer (score 17):

I think
F#'s pipe forward operator (**`|>`**) should  vs [(**&**)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-) in haskell.

```hs
// pipe operator example in haskell

factorial :: (Eq a, Num a) =>  a -> a
factorial x =
  case x of
    1 -> 1
    _ -> x * factorial (x-1)
```

```sh
// terminal
ghic >> 5 & factorial & show
```

If you dont like (**`&`**) operator, you can custom it like F# or Elixir :

```hs
(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(|>) x f = f x
infixl 1 |>
```

```sh
ghci>> 5 |> factorial |> show
```

Why `infixl 1 |>`? See the doc in [Data-Function (&)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html)

> infixl = infix + left associativity
>
> infixr = infix + right associativity

---

## (.)

(**`.`**) means function composition. It means [(f.g)(x) = f(g(x))](https://learnyoua.haskell.sg/content/zh-cn/ch06/composition.png) in Math.

```hs
foo = negate . (*3)
```

```sh
// ouput -3
ghci>> foo 1
// ouput -15
ghci>> foo 5
```

it equals

```hs
// (1)
foo x = negate (x * 3)
```

or

```hs
// (2)
foo x = negate $ x * 3
```

(**`$`**) operator is also defind in [Data-Function ($)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html).

(**`.`**) is used for create `Hight Order Function` or `closure in js`. See example:

```hs
// (1) use lamda expression to create a Hight Order Function
ghci> map (\x -> negate (abs x)) [5,-3,-6,7,-3,2,-19,24]  
[-5,-3,-6,-7,-3,-2,-19,-24]


// (2) use . operator to create a Hight Order Function
ghci> map (negate . abs) [5,-3,-6,7,-3,2,-19,24]  
[-5,-3,-6,-7,-3,-2,-19,-24]
```

Wow, Less (code) is better.

---

## Compare `|>` and `.`

```sh
ghci> 5 |> factorial |> show

// equals

ghci> (show . factorial) 5 

// equals

ghci> show . factorial $ 5
```

It is the different between `left —> right` and `right —> left`. ⊙﹏⊙|||

## Humanization

`|>` and `&` is better than `.`

because

```hs
ghci> sum (replicate 5 (max 6.7 8.9))

// equals

ghci> 8.9 & max 6.7 & replicate 5 & sum

// equals

ghci> 8.9 |> max 6.7 |> replicate 5 |> sum

// equals

ghci> (sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7) 8.9

// equals

ghci> sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7 $ 8.9
```

## How to functional programming in object-oriented language?

please visit http://reactivex.io/

It support :

- Java: RxJava
- JavaScript: RxJS
- C#: Rx.NET
- C#(Unity): UniRx
- Scala: RxScala
- Clojure: RxClojure
- C++: RxCpp
- Lua: RxLua
- Ruby: Rx.rb
- Python: RxPY
- Go: RxGo
- Groovy: RxGroovy
- JRuby: RxJRuby
- Kotlin: RxKotlin
- Swift: RxSwift
- PHP: RxPHP
- Elixir: reaxive
- Dart: RxDart

Comment: The only issue that I see with replacing |> in FSharp with & in Haskell is that you can (allegedly) not use it at the start of a line.

Answer (score 15):

Aside from style and culture, this boils down to optimizing the language design for either pure or impure code.

The `|>` operator is common in F# largely because it helps to hide two limitations that appear with predominantly-impure code:

- Left-to-right type inference without structural subtypes.
- The value restriction.

Note that the former limitation does not exist in OCaml because subtyping is structural instead of nominal, so the structural type is easily refined via unification as type inference progresses.

Haskell takes a different trade-off, choosing to focus on predominantly-pure code where these limitations can be lifted.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first day to try Haskell (after Rust and F#), and I was able to define F#'s |> operator:

```
(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(|>) x f = f x
infixl 0 |>
```

and it seems to work:

```
factorial x =
  case x of
    1 -> 1
    _ -> x * factorial (x-1)

main =     
    5 |> factorial |> print
```

I bet a Haskell expert can give you an even better solution.

Comment: you can also define infix operators infix :)

`x |> f = f x`