# Is there an inverse of the Haskell $ operator?

Tags: haskell, operators, dollar-sign

A quick question, is there an operator in Haskell that works like the dollar sign but gives precedence to the left hand side. I.E. instead of

```
f (x 1)
```

being written as

```
f $ x 1
```

I'd like to write it as

```
x 1 $ f
```

This is purely a stylistic thing. I'm running a sequence of functions in order and it would be nice if I could write them left to right to match that I read left to right. If there an operator for this?

[update] A couple of people have asked if I can't define my own. In answer, I wanted to check there wasn't an existing operator before I reinvented the wheel.

Comment: This is like F#'s pipeline composition operator. Related discussion (on why it's not built into Haskell): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457140/haskell-composition-vs-fs-pipe-forward-operator

Comment: It looks like the answer to my question is "no". Thank you :)

Comment: You realize you're combining both left-to-right and right-to-left application in the same expression, don't you? Most people I think would baulk at this. Reverse application is the so called T-combinator. It was often denoted with (#) a few years ago, but now # is a special symbol in GHC, so it is no longer used much.

Comment: you want: f (g 1). Why not just f . g $ 1?

Comment: @demi I believe OP is looking to express f (g 1) in a left-to-right pipeline. `f . g $ 1` is the opposite of that

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As of GHC 7.10 (`base` 4.8.0.0), `&` is in `Data.Function`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html

Answer (score 36):

In Haskell you can use `flip` to change arguments' order of any binary function or operator:

```
ghci> let (|>) = flip ($)
ghci> 3 |> (+4) |> (*6)
42
```

Comment: Does it keep the same operator precedence?

Answer (score 21):

I do not know, whether there is an standart operator, but what prevents you from writing your own? This works in ghci:

```
Prelude> let a $> b = b a
Prelude> 1 $> (+2)
3
Prelude> sum [1, 2] $> (+2)
5
Prelude> map (+2) [1, 2] $> map (+3)
[6,7]
```

**UPDATE**: searching on hoogle for `a -> (a -> b) -> b` (it is the type of this operator) found nothing useful.

Comment: Looks I'll be using this, thank you. An £ appeals to me for the operator.

Comment: @Benjamin Confino: Puns are always enjoyable, but for real-world use I'd suggest considering `|>`. As noted above, that operator in F# does exactly what you're looking for, so using the same name will help people understand your code more easily.

Comment: It is one of Haskell's real strengths that you can write your own control flow operators.  Haskell doesn't have a "loop" construct? No problem! Just write your own.

Comment: `|>` is used by Data.Sequence. `#` sounds like a better idea.

Comment: Link: [Hoogle search for `a -> (a -> b) -> b`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+b). The only results with that exact type are [`($)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-36-) and [`($!)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-36--33-).

Answer (score 10):

This combinator is defined (tongue in cheek) in the [data-aviary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary) package:

```
Prelude Data.Aviary.BirdsInter> 1 `thrush` (+2)
Loading package data-aviary-0.2.3 ... linking ... done.
3
```

Although actually using that package is a rather silly thing to do, reading the source is fun, and reveals that [this combinator](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-aviary/0.2.3/doc/html/src/Data-Aviary-BirdsInter.html#thrush) is formed via the magic incantation of `flip id` (or, in ornithological parlance, `cardinal idiot`).

Comment: ``caridinalIdiot`` is a magnificent combinator name!

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any standard version, but I've seen (#) used for that purpose in a couple places.  The one in particular that comes to mind is HOC, which uses it in an idiom like:

```
someObject # someMessage param1 param2
```

I seem to recall seeing other "object-oriented" libraries using the # operator in the same way, but cannot remember how many or which ones.

Comment: Wash uses (#). Erik Meijer, Daan Leijen and James Hook used it to script MS Agent with Active Haskell (a Haskell-COM bridge). Possibly the initial Haskell / ObjectiveC bridge also used (#).

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just redefine `$`.

```
let ($) x f = f x
```

Or just choose a different operator, like `$$`