# Haskell "Dot Hack"

Tags: haskell

In the [Wiki page for Sudoku solutions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Sudoku#Chaining_style_Solver), one solution claims to use the "Dot Hack". The linked Github page is no more available and I couldn't find anything about it elewhere.

What is this about? What does it do? How?

Comment: I wonder if it's related to the .hack series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess he's referring to the following line:

```
import Prelude hiding ((.))
```

which disables the normal `(.)` operator for functional composition. Instead, another operator with the same name is used, probably imported from the utility module `T.T`. This operator behaves like in OOP languages:

```
pretty_output solution = solution.elems.map(show).in_group_of(9)
    .map(unwords).unlines
```

which (I think) would normally look like

```
pretty_output solution = (unlines . map unwords . in_group_of 9 . map show . elems) solution
```

That operator works the same like the [`|>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340273) operator in F#:

```
(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
x |> f = f x
```

which is used to *pipe* a value through functions (and is more readable and better functional style, imo):

```
pretty_output solution = solution |> elems |> map show |> in_group_of 9 |> map unwords |> unlines
```

`(|>)` is also the same as `flip ($)`.

Edit: This "hacked" operator already exists in Haskell, somehow. The same composition behavior can be achieved by the left-to-right composition operator from [`Control.Category`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Category.html#v%3a-62--62--62-):

```
g x = x |> (f1 >>> f2 >>> f3)
```

This pipes only functions, though, and is actually just `f >>> g = g . f`.

Comment: You might also like to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1457140/1346276), treating some issues with both versions.

Answer (score 4):

It's using the OOP style

```
thing.method
```

to call functions on `thing` instead of the usual

```
method thing
```

See for example

```
row i = i `div` 9
col i = i `mod` 9
row_list i positions = positions.select(on_i_row) where
  on_i_row pos = pos.row  == i.row
col_list i positions = positions.select(on_i_col) where
  on_i_col pos = pos.col == i.col
```

in that programme.