# :: a -> (a -> b) -> b operator (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

Writing Haskell programs I found myself in need of an operator like this.

```
(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(|>) = flip ($)
infixl 0 |>
```

I think it is useful when glueing many functions together.

```
tText cs = someFun cs   |>
           lines        |>
           map (drop 4) |>
           reverse
```

I prefer it over `.` because with `|>` the order in which the functions are applied is the same as the order in which the functions are written.

```
tText' cs = reverse      . 
            map (drop 4) . 
            lines        . 
            someFun $ cs
```

Question is: is this (`|>`) something that already exists in the `Prelude` / some other basic library? Reimplementing simple stuff is something silly which I would like to avoid.

A Hoogle search did not help. Closest thing I found was `>>>` (Arrows), but it seems an overkill.

Comment: No, it doesn't, although as you say `>>>` does.  [There was another SO question about why F# uses `|>` where Haskell uses `.` and `$`, which is pretty relevant.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457140/haskell-composition-vs-fs-pipe-forward-operator)  (Note also, just for fun, that with `.` or `>>>`, you can write your function point-free: `tText = reverse . map (drop 4) . lines . someFun`, or `tText = someFun >>> lines >>> map (drop 4) >>> reverse`.)

Comment: Some time ago, there was a conversation on the mailing list about adding this to the standard libraries. http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2012-November/018832.html

Comment: "the order in which the functions are applied is the same as the order in which the functions are written."   Well – that's the kind of thinking Haskellers avoid: you don't specify "do this, then with the result do that, then..." but focus on the _desired result_, so it's perfectly natural to start with the last calculation step. Also, what with lazy evaluation, this "last" step will actually be the first to be evaluated! — For the procedural kind of functions, the ones where you actually need to think in sequential steps, Haskell has Monads, whose `do` notation is always "forwards".

Comment: Found this http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reverse-apply/latest/doc/html/Control-Apply-Reverse.html

Comment: also, `tText cs = ($ cs) $   someFun    >>>
           lines        >>>
           map (drop 4) >>>
           reverse`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there isn't anything in a standard library that I know of. Years and years ago a lot of my code imported my breif but handy `Forwards` module:

```
> module Forwards where

> infixl 0 |>
> infixl 9 .>

> (|>) = flip ($)
> (.>) = flip (.)
```

I even used the same name as you!

These days I don't use it much at all - I got used to the order that function composition uses.

Feel free to use your own handy shortcuts.

I also use `$` less than I used to. Where I used to write

```
thing = this $ that arg $ an other $ it
```

Now I write

```
thing = this . that arg . an other $ it
```

Answer (score 12):

The [`lens` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) defines [this operator as `&`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.8.7.3/doc/html/Control-Lens-Combinators.html).

Comment: And.. `diagrams` defines it as `#`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also define (|>) as "flip id", and understanding why this works is a great lesson in type inference by unification as used in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience goes, I don't know any such library. And if such a library exists, I'd advise against using it.

---

Unless you are using the lens package, I'd suggest not to use externally defined operators of that kind. (In case of that lens package, you really need and already have such an operator.)

In my experience, IMHO and such ...

In cases where the readability enhances with a forward composition in contrast to the usual composition (not only when dealing with lenses), it is beneficial to define a special operator in that module or locally via `let` or `where`. For that, I tend to use single unicode symbols rather than ascii combos.

```
(·) = flip (.)
infixl 1 (·)

(§) = ($) -- left associative, no flip
infixl 0 (§)
```

Some years ago(, when there were no lenses), I thought of defining my own module for these, too. But then I grow to use that module sooo infrequent that I tended to reinvent the wheel anyway. To have these operators in a library may even *increase* the effort of reading the code: The reader has to look those rarely used operators up. In that case, locally defined operators are way better.