# F# lookup issues on recursive types

Tags: f#

I am trying to create two types where one is able to remove itself from the other such as in this example.

```
type employee (workplace : Job) =
    member this.Fire () = workplace.Employees.Remove(this) |> ignore
and Job () =
    let employees = new ResizeArray<employee>()
    member this.Employees = employees
```

But this gets me the compile error of "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the problem even without reordering the declarations - when the F# compiler type-checks the `Employee` declaration, it doesn't yet know what is the type of `workplace.Employees` (because the type hasn't been declared yet), so it doesn't know where does the `Remove` method come from. You can correct that by adding type annotation that specifies that `Employees` is `ResizeArray<Employee>`:

```
type Employee (workplace : Job) =
    member this.Fire () = 
      let emps : ResizeArray<Employee> = workplace.Employees
      emps.Remove(this) |> ignore

and Job () =
    let employees = new ResizeArray<Employee>()
    member this.Employees = employees
```

However, this example isn't very functional - if you're going to use mutable state (such as `ResizeArray`), then the state should be hidden as private state of the type (so `Jobs` could have a `Remove` method).

In general, declaring recursive type declarations is a bit less comfortable in F# - however, you shouldn't need them that often. Quite frequently, you can use more generic types (i.e. `Job` may not need to know abou the `Employee` type).

Comment: What do you mean by "Quite frequently, you can use more generic types (i.e. Job may not need to know abou the Employee type)." What would I use in its place? In my own code I did end up making my own Fire method in the chat type.

Comment: In this case, `Job` is just a generic collectiob, so it doesn't need to know about `Employee`, but of course, this is just a simplified example - in more complex case, you could use some interface and avoid the recursive type declaration too. I think mutual recursion is probavly more often needed in OO design.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
type Job () =
    let employees = new ResizeArray<employee>()
    member this.Employees = employees
and employee (workplace : Job) =
    member this.Fire () = workplace.Employees.Remove(this) |> ignore
```

Comment: That does fix it. Do you happen to know why? The only thing I could come up with is that because the compiler goes from the top down it simply has no idea what a Job is. However, I thought the and keyword made the compiler take a second pass at compilation to resolve this. Clearly I was wrong. I don't suppose you know what it does?

Comment: "Job" hasn't been declared yet when you reference it for "employee".

Comment: `type...and` has a two-pass type inference algorithm; first it looks at all the explicit method signatures, top to bottom, and then does a second pass on the method bodies, top to bottom.  Here the body of one method needs info from the body of another.

Comment: (Possibly see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844733/why-cant-fs-type-inference-handle-this though that is mostly basics, whereas this is a more advanced aspect of the type inference algorithm for recursive members.)